# I always get TypeError: item is undefined on line 9 and dont know why

Tags: jquery, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from 'reactstrap';

function RenderCard({item}) {
  return(
      <Card>
          <CardImg src={item.image} alt={item.name} /> //Here
          <CardBody>
          <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
          if(item.designation) {
             <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle>
           } else {
                  return null 
               } //If statement
          <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
          </CardBody>
      </Card>
  );
}

function Home(props) {
  return(
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row align-items-start">
          <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard item={props.dish} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard item={props.promotion} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard item={props.leader} />
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 issues.

1. it uses `item` when `item` may still  be undefined
2. it uses an `if` statement inside the `jsx` section (you can only use the shorthand ternary operator as below)

Change your code like this

```
function RenderCard({item}) {
    return(
        <>
            {item ?
                <Card>
                    <CardImg src={item.image} alt={item.name} /> //Here
                        <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
                        {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle> : undefined}
                        <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card> : undefined
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks it now renders to the screen but it now only renders one card when its suppose to render 3

Comment: Can you verify that all three `props.dish`, `props.promotion`, and `props.leader` are defined? you can try to `console.log` like this: under `<RenderCard item={props.promotion} />` write `{console.log(props.promotion)}` and so on under each `RenderCard `

Comment: @Popperjs Please consider marking as excepted if it worked for you to help anyone having the same issue in the future.